# React Navigation when switching to another screen, triggering the function on that screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I trigger the function on that screen when switching to another screen?
I open the AddLeadScreen screen from the LeadScreen screen. I add a lead from the AddLeadScreen screen and when I say ok, I want it to go back to the LeadScreen screen but refresh that page. How can I do that ?

```
Alert.alert(
    'Success',
    'Added Lead.',
    [
        { text: 'Okay', onPress: () =>  navigate('Lead') }
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

**AddLeadScreen.js**

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('Lead', { refreshPage: true })
```

**LeadScreen.js**

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.navigation.state && this.props.navigation.state.params && prevProps.navigation.state) {
        if (this.props.navigation.state.params !== prevProps.navigation.state.params) {
            const shouldRefresh = this.props.navigation.state.params.refreshPage
            if (shouldRefresh) {
               // actually refresh the page
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I try but get this error... TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state.params')